Pixi install fails with stable-retro
building version 0.9.2 of stable-retro gets me the following error:
error: could not create 'build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\retro\data\stable\TaiyouNoYuushaFighbird-Nes\LeftPlayerOption.Level1.TopMachineOption.state': No such file or directory
I'm using
pixi install
to install the dependencies, as referenced here:
https://pixi.sh/latest/tutorials/python/#managing-both-conda-and-pypi-dependencies-in-pixi
I'm new to the python eco system. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.
my pixi.toml:
[project]
name = "pixi-neat"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Add a short description here"
channels = ["conda-forge"]
platforms = ["win-64"]

[tasks]

[pypi-dependencies]
gymnasium = { version = "==0.29.1" }
stable-retro = { version = "==0.9.2" }

[dependencies]
python = "==3.10.14"

Using Windows 10
I called
pixi install
in the respective directory. My expectation was that it would install the library correctly.

https://github.com/farama-foundation/stable-retro?tab=readme-ov-file#supported-specs doesn't say that plain windows is supported but WSL should be used.
